# What does ProgrammingError mean?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I am having these `ProgrammingError`s occurring on my production server lately. The page which the user is submitting a form at is a `UserCreateView` and is being redirected to the `phone-verification` page. The error reads:

```
Internal Server Error: /phone-verification/

ProgrammingError at /phone-verification/
column quiz_sitting.percent_correct does not exist
LINE 1: ...rrect_questions", "quiz_sitting"."current_score", "quiz_sitt...
                                                             ^
```

I am not sure why its looking at `quiz_sitting` in the database because `/phone-verification/` has nothing to do with that. The view for `/phone-verification/` looks like this:

```
@login_required
def phone_verify_check(request):
    employee = request.user
    phone_verify, _ = PhoneVerify.objects.get_or_create(employee=employee)
    login_tracker = EmployeeLogin.objects.create(employee=employee, ip_address=get_client_ip(request))
    login_tracker.save()
    if phone_verify.verified:
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        return redirect('resend')
```

I am using Django tenant schemas for handling subdomains which means when I run a migration it looks like:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate_schemas --shared
python manage.py migrate_schemas --tenant
```

I recently deleted all my migrations because I was having these `ProgrammingError`s on another page and then I ran the `makemigrations` etc again and it seemed to have fix it. But now it is occurring again. I really hope there isn't some sort of corruption in the database like columns being mixed up. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That you made a query that the database does not understand. Here it is because a column is missing. Deleting all migrations usually is not a good idea, or at least not if you run it on an existing database.

Comment: Could it be querying `quiz_sitting.percent_correct` because the database is messed up? Because there is no query in this code that should be calling that.